# How to unit test a python version switch

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-3.x, pytest

How can I write a unit test for the following function:

```
def version_switch():
    if sys.version_info.major < 3:
        print('not python 3')
    else:
        print('python 3')
```

My first thought was mocking `sys.version_info.major` but as it is a read only attribute it will not do.

To be sure: I do run my test suite under py3 and py2 using tox. however, each run will only check one code path. The actual function does not use any language specific features. Should I look for alternative ways to determine the version, ones that are easier to mock?

Comment: "the actual function does not use any language specific features" -- Then what _does_ it do?  Why look at `sys.version_info` in the first place?

Comment: Are you asking how to get 100% code coverage in each version?

Comment: @SamDufel I asked because I don't like not covering without good reason. I don't need to see a 100, but I want to know that I didn't take shortcuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may not be able to swap out the value of `major` on `sys.version_info`, but you can swap out the value of `version_info` on `sys`:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import mock
>>> with mock.patch.object(sys, 'version_info') as v_info:
...   v_info.major = 3
...   print(sys.version_info.major)
... 
3
```

Note that I'm using python2.7, but I convinced `sys` to tell me that I'm using python3.x.

Comment: I was getting `AttributeError: sys does not have the attribute 'version_info'` because I accidentally was using 'sys' rather than `sys` so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> however, each run will only check one code path

So?

You don't *care* what the Python 3 code path would do if you ran it on Python 2, or vice versa. There's no need to test that. Just check that the output correctly corresponds to the Python version you're running on.

Comment: I disagree. From a unit test point of view the function foes not need to care what the value in ``sys.version_info`` represents. Something that should be reflected by the fact that it is covered both ways.

Comment: @Elbenfreund: From a unit test point of view, the unit under test needs to determine what Python version it's running on, and you need to test that it does that. If you want to, say, test the function's ability to compare the `major` attribute of some object to `3`, you might want to refactor this function to use a helper function that takes a version info object and compares its `major` attribute to `3`. Then you can test the helper straightforwardly.

Comment: What you're asking for here sounds a lot like trying to test the base case code path of a recursive Fibonacci function for `fib(5)`, or test the recursive case code path for `fib(1)`.