# Dealing with MagicMock Conversions in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

The context is I'm trying to unit test some Python code that involves a Python version being checked for. I had this working under the `platform` approach, but I was told using `platform` is not a great idea and I should use `sys.version_info` instead. Thus I have the following logic:

```
def main() -> None:
  python_version = f"{sys.version_info[0]}.{sys.version_info[1]}"

  if float(python_version) < 3.7:
     sys.stderr.write("\nQuendor requires Python 3.7 or later.\n")
     sys.stderr.write(f"Your current version is {python_version}\n\n")
     sys.exit(1)
```

(I do realize I could also do `if sys.version_info < (3, 7):` for my check.)

My unit test is this:

```
def test_bad_python_version(capsys) -> None:
    import sys
    from quendor.__main__ import main

    with mock.patch.object(sys, "version_info") as v_info:
        v_info.major = 3
        v_info.minor = 5

        main()

    terminal_text = capsys.readouterr()
    print(terminal_text)
```

Here my test isn't complete, of course. I'm trying to print the output just to make sure the test is working.

Running that test gets me this:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
"<MagicMock name='version_info.__getitem__()'
id='1417904973808'>.<MagicMock name='version_info.__getitem__()'
id='1417904973808'>"
```

Incidentally, if my switch my condition in `main` to this (`if sys.version_info < (3, 7):`) I get a similar but different error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'tuple'
```

I'm not sure how to get the version_info passed in correctly, which I think is my issue here. I have searched the documentation and I've seen other questions here (example: [How to unit test a python version switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022926/how-to-unit-test-a-python-version-switch)) about MagicMock but nothing that just definitively states: "This is how to do this."

I should note that I had a version working perfectly fine when using `platform`. That version of my test looked like this:

```
with mock.patch.object(
        platform,
        "python_version",
        return_value="3.5",
    ), pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
        main()

    terminal_text = capsys.readouterr()
    expect(terminal_text.err).to(contain("Quendor requires Python 3.7"))
```

Key to that seemed to be the "return_value" I was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your unit test you are setting/mocking the version by doing

```
v_info.major = 3
v_info.minor = 5
```

but accessing `sys.version_info[0]` or `sys.version_info[1]`.

Try to change your version extraction in `main()` to

```
python_version = f"{sys.version_info.major}.{sys.version_info.minor}"
```

Worked for me:

```
In [8]: with mock.patch.object(sys, "version_info") as v_info:
   ...:     v_info.major = 3
   ...:     v_info.minor = 5
   ...:     main()
   ...: 

Quendor requires Python 3.7 or later.
Your current version is 3.5
```

Comment: That was entirely it! I wasn't considering a change to my actual code, thinking all this had to be an issue with how I was mocking in the first place. Much thanks. This did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You are patching it this way:

```
with mock.patch.object(sys, "version_info") as v_info:
    v_info.major = 3
    v_info.minor = 5
```

Thus, it will be applied to the following calls:

```
sys.version_info.major  # Will display 3
sys.version_info.minor  # Will display 5
```

But instead, what you accessed in the source code was different:

```
sys.version_info
sys.version_info[0]
sys.version_info[1]
```

Obviously, your patches wouldn't reflect because they are targeted to `.major` and `.minor` but those aren't called anyways. Instead, change the patch to be applied to `sys.version_info` which should return a tuple of items `(3, 5)` so that it would reflect since it's the one called in your source code. No need to change anything from the source code:

**src.py**

```
import sys


def main() -> None:
    print("Call main")
    python_version = f"{sys.version_info[0]}.{sys.version_info[1]}"

    if float(python_version) < 3.7:
        print("Quendor requires Python 3.7 or later.")


def main2() -> None:
    print("Call main2")
    if sys.version_info < (3, 7):
        print("Quendor requires Python 3.7 or later.")
```

**test_src.py**

```
import sys
from unittest import mock

from src import main, main2


def test_bad_python_version():
    with mock.patch.object(sys, "version_info", (3, 5)) as v_info:
        main()
        main2()

def test_good_python_version():
    with mock.patch.object(sys, "version_info", (3, 8)) as v_info:
        main()
        main2()
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q -rP
..                                                                                            [100%]
============================================== PASSES ===============================================
______________________________________ test_bad_python_version ______________________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
Call main
Quendor requires Python 3.7 or later.
Call main2
Quendor requires Python 3.7 or later.
_____________________________________ test_good_python_version ______________________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
Call main
Call main2
2 passed in 0.06s
```